# Запятая перед "или", или Где взять правило со штампом "Уплочено"?

Tags: пунктуация

> (7) Будешь ли ты доискиваться, где блуждал Улисс, вместо того чтобы
>   положить конец собственным заблуждениям? Нет времени слушать, носило
>   ли его между Италией и Сицилией или за пределами известного нам мира.
>   Да и не мог он на таком малом пространстве скитаться так долго.
>   Душевные бури швыряют нас ежедневно, из-за собственной негодности мы
>   терпим все Улиссовы беды. И красота прельщает наше зренье, и враг
>   грозит; здесь – свирепые чудовища, лакомые до человеческой крови, там
>   – коварный соблазн, привлекающий слух, и все разнообразье бед. Научи
>   меня, как любить родину, жену, отца, как плыть к этой столь честной
>   цели даже после кораблекрушенья. (8) Зачем ты доискиваешься, **была ли
>   Пенелопа вправду целомудренна[3], или обманула свой век**? Подозревала
>   ли она, что видит Улисса еще прежде, чем узнала наверное? Лучше
>   объясни мне, что такое целомудрие, и какое в нем благо, и в чем оно
>   заключено – в теле или в душе?

[источник](http://au95.org/1/read_book/48/28)

---

**[ЛИ/ЛЬ... ИЛИ, *союз*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_392)**

> ...Запятая перед «или» ставится, если «ли/ль… или» соединяют части
>   сложносочиненного предложения, в том числе вопросительного («ли/ль…
>   или» в данном случае рассматриваются как повторяющийся союз).
>
> *Плохо ли вам было у Плюшкина, или, просто, по своей охоте гуляете по лесам да дерете прохожих?* Н. Гоголь, Мертвые души. *Во сне ль всё это
>   снится мне, // Или гляжу я в самом деле, // На что при этой же луне //
>   С тобой живые мы глядели?* Ф. Тютчев, Опять стою я над Невой... *Идет
>   ли дождь, или светит солнце – ему всё равно.*
>
> Запятая перед «или» ставится, если «ли/ль… или» соединяют однородные
>   придаточные предложения («ли/ль… или» в данном случае также
>   рассматриваются как повторяющийся союз).
>
> *Я девять лет не видал своей маменьки и не знал, жива ли она, или кости ее лежат уже в сырой земле.* Л. Толстой, Отрочество.

Где тут случай Пенелопы без Улисса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Серж прав.

*Зачем ты доискиваешься, была ли Пенелопа вправду целомудренна или обманула свой век?*  - СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, которое представляет из себя предложение с однородными членами. При однородных членах «ли/ль… или» не рассматриваются как повторяющийся союз, запятая не ставится.

Вот если бы было так:*"Зачем ты доискиваешься, была ли Пенелопа вправду целомудренна, или она обманула свой век?"*, тогда бы запятая  была, ведь она разделяла бы однородные придаточные, а там «ли/ль… или» считаются повторяющимся союзом.

Answer (score 2):

Вот правило: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139#pp139

Примечание. Для конструкций с союзами ли…или устанавливаются следующие пунктуационные правила:
1) если ли…или соединяют однородные члены предложения, запятая перед или не ставится: Поддержит ли он меня или не поддержит? [См. § 13, п. 12.] **Ср. однородные члены с этим же союзом в придаточной части:** Нехлюдов понял это слово и этот взгляд так, что она хочет знать, **держится ли он своего решения или принял её отказ и изменил его** (Л. Т.);

Зачем ты доискиваешься, была ли Пенелопа вправду целомудренна или обманула свой век?

Это не два однородных придаточных, а одно придаточное предложение с однородными членами. Союз ЛИ...ИЛИ считается одиночным. Частица ЛИ выражает сомнение, а также используется в качестве подчинительного союза в СПП.

Answer (score 1):

В приведенном Вами примере союз *ли...или* соединяет однородные сказуемые в придаточном предложении. Поэтому указанная запятая не нужна.

Правило таково:

12. Союзы ли…или, стоящие при однородных членах предложения, не приравниваются к повторяющимся, поэтому запятая перед или не ставится: ***Видит ли он это или не видит? (Г.); Было ли это на самом деле или нет?***

Д. Э. Розенталь.

Comment: Спасибо, Сержик! Боюсь, что "мой случай" - это Плюшкин: ***Плохо ли вам было у Плюшкина, или, просто, по своей охоте гуляете по лесам да дерете прохожих?*** Только я не согласна!..

Comment: В примере, который вы приводите, два сказуемых зависят от одного подлежащего - Пенелопа. В примере же из справочника Розенталя иной случай: первое предложение безличное, второе определенно личное.